# Can a storage account mapped to a Azure function app be used for other functionalities?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have an existing storage account mapped to a Azure function.

For a new implementation for the same application, I need to create a new container in the storage account and upload the files. Please let me know if it is fine to reuse the same storage account mapped to a azure function app or to create a new one. Till now, the storage account is only used as it is needed for the function app.

Comment: Yes, the same storage account can be used for multiple function apps. Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#shared-storage-accounts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reuse it for other purposes, but it really depends on the situation. It is not recommended for performance reasons:

> To maximize performance, use a separate storage account for each function app. This is particularly important when you have Durable Functions or Event Hub triggered functions, which both generate a high volume of storage transactions. When your application logic interacts with Azure Storage, either directly (using the Storage SDK) or through one of the storage bindings, you should use a dedicated storage account. For example, if you have an Event Hub-triggered function writing some data to blob storage, use two storage accounts—one for the function app and another for the blobs being stored by the function.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#optimize-storage-performance))

Since storage accounts are cheap, I see no reason not to seperate them. You might want to apply different security rules or policies as well to the different storage accounts.

If you want to reuse the same storage account for other Azure Functions you need to be aware of possible [host ID collisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#host-id-considerations).